# Which episode is this where Saber dress in white and bounded?

Tags: fate-stay-night

In *Unlimited Blade Works*, which episode was Saber bounded up and was in a white dress being raped by Caster?

[image: Saber in white dress being bounded]

Comment: You can find answer [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20629/why-is-saber-wearing-a-white-wedding-dress-and-why-was-she-posed-like-that)

Comment: Its Fate stay night second season episode 1

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki *Fate/Stay Night* doesn't have a second season unless your referring to *Fate/Stay Night: Unlimited Blade Works* which does. it's important to know that there's a difference in title for 2 different plots

Comment: i haven't seen *Fate/Stay Night: Unlimited Blade Works* but going by the original Visual Novel Saber isn't raped here, Caster is actually torturing her

Comment: @Memor-X yes you are correct it is Fate stay night Unlimited blade works, I got ended typing fate stay night only..

Comment: @Ichigo Kurosaki actually, that question is about the the reason for the clothes. It doesn't say anything about where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Saber wears - or more exactly is made to wear - those clothes in Fate/Stay Night: Unlimited Blade Works episode 13, 14, 17 and 18. (Or season 2 episode 1, 2, 5 and 6, if you count the series as two seasons.)

The screenshot itself is from episode 13 (or S2 episode 1).

By the way she isn't being raped (not even in the visual novel). Caster just tortures her to make her lose her mind so she would want the pleasure by herself.